# Compare jquery .data() with String always false

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6d82Q/1/

In my HTML I have:

```
<div class="myClass" data-status="true"></div>
<div class="myClass" data-status="false"></div>
```

I want to add a CSS-class to a div depending on the status:

```
$('.myClass').each(function()
{ 
    // compare status
    if($(this).data('status') == 'true')
    {
        $(this).addClass('myTrueClass');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).addClass('myFalseClass');
    }
});
```

The Problem is, that always `myFalseClass` is added. 
My question is: How can the problem be fixed and why does it occur in the first place?

Comment: [You might find my answer to a different question relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7262427/497418).

Comment: Remove the quotes around `true` in the comparison.  true and "true" are not the same thing.  true == "1", not "true".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/) will perform some auto-casting on `[data-*]` attributes, which makes passing data to the client very convenient.

As you're storing what would be auto-cast to a boolean, you can use:

```
if ($(this).data('status')) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

If you need to make sure that the value is `true`, and not just truthy (like a value of `1`) then be sure to use a reference comparison:

```
if ($(this).data('status') === true) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

---

As an aside, there's no reason to call `.each()` when you could simply pass a function to `.addClass()`:

```
$('.myClass').addClass(function () {
    return $(this).data('status') ? 'myTrueClass' : 'myFalseClass';
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try,

```
$('.myClass').each(function()
{ 
    if($(this).data('status'))
    {
        $(this).addClass('myTrueClass');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).addClass('myFalseClass');
    }
});
```

Since `.data(key)` would automatically convert that "true" into a boolean.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/6d82Q/2/)

For sure, if you want to get that "true" as a string then just use `.attr("data-status")`

Answer (score 2):

you have to do like this:

```
if($(this).data('status') === true)
{
    $('#out').append('true <br>');
}
else
{
    $('#out').append('false <br>');
}
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/r6RZM/)